# Rest call failed with client error in ADF pipeline

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

[image]

Trying to create a pipeline with REST API, with copy activity, linkedservice test connection is succeeded, but pipeline failed with error.
User Configuration issue,
Failure happened on Source side. Error code=Restcall failed with client error,
Status code 401 Unauthorised, please check your activity settings

Comment: please add full error message.

Comment: what is your authentication type for rest APi linked service

Answer (score 0):

> User Configuration issue, Failure happened on Source side. Error code=Restcall failed with client error, Status code 401 Unauthorised, please check your activity settings

***The error you are facing is because the authorization you are using is not correct or invalid authentication credentials for the request.***

**To call devops API from ADF you can follow below steps:**

- In the URL of REST API linked service Provide your devops API URL
- In the REST API linked service set Authentication is to '**None**'
- In the headers, I added a field '**Authorization**' with the value '**Basic xxxx**' where 'xxxx' is my personal access token ([PAT token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?toc=/azure/devops/organizations/toc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows)) Ensure the PAT has the necessary to access the required resources.

Answer (score 0):

I can send the REST API call successfully with the following setting. The Authentication method is `Basic`. The Username can be any value. The password is your personal access token (PAT) with the right permission.

[image]